# Excel Formula Question

Tags: excel

How do I write the formula that would mean this: If `X<$999.00` then multiply by 0% If `X >$1000.00` but `< $1499.00` then multiply by 10% If `X > $1499.00` but `< $1999.00` then multiply by 15% If `X > $1999.00` then multiply by $20%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this meets the specifications of your question, but some things are ambiguous (your conditions exclude everything between $999.00 and $1000.00 inclusive, for example) so I guessed at what your real intent was.

This formula will return:

- 0 if X < $1000
- 10% of X if X >= $1000 and X < $1500
- 15% of X if X >= $1500 and X < $2000
- 20% of X in all other cases

```
=IF(X < 1000, 0, IF(X < 1500, X * 0.1, IF(X < 2000, X * 0.15, X * 0.2)))
```